# Using Localstorage with Redux in React

Tags: reactjs, web, redux, browser, local-storage

I am working on an ecommerce site in React/Redux. I want to save the user's cart into the localstorage each time after an `action` has been dispatched in Redux. My code for that looks like this -

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    cart: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      state.cart = [...state.cart, action.payload];
      localStorage.setItem("Cart", JSON.stringify(state.cart));
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      state.cart = [];
    },
  },
});

export const { addToCart, removeFromCart } = cartSlice.actions;

export const selectCart = (state) => state.cart.cart;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

I did this to solve the problem of the cart getting empty whenever the site refreshes (because I was storing cart in `state`).

But here, everything works fine until the site refreshes. The products get added to the localstorage.

Now, when I refresh my site, since I am setting localstorage to the `state` of the cart, each time I refresh, the previous localstorage gets deleted and is overridden by the new state of the cart (because even the `state` of cart gets changed after refresh).

Is there any other way around it?

I tried by best to explain what I'm facing. Hope it's understandable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hook your setting of localStorage stuff into your components or moreover the button that calls the `addToCart` action. In this way, you're only persisting items whenever user actually click on the add to cart button.

Comment: You mean I should add items into localstorage in the `addToCartHandler` itself?                                                                                              ```const addToCartHandler = () => {
    history.push("/cart");
    dispatch(addToCart(product));
  };```

Comment: Also I was wondering what is done on a production level? Is it a good practice to store the cart in the user's database or just in localstorage?

Comment: Look into the `redux-persist` package.